# Php outputting records in a while loop - error

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a while loop that will go through my query results and output my php and html. I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to output the following code.In PHP while loop when i gave the below code its not showing the $currency output. But when i give '$currency' separately its showing the output. Whats the mistake i am making?

```
while($list1=mysql_fetch_array($add1))
echo '<tr><td>'.$list1['export_charges'].'&nbsp;$currency</td></tr>';
echo $currency; // This is working
}
```

Comment: If you use a variable in a string - you should use double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
while($list1=mysql_fetch_array($add1))
echo '<tr><td>'.$list1['export_charges'].'&nbsp;'.$currency.'</td></tr>';
echo $currency; // This is working
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While using html in echo, one should use double quotes.

```
while ( $list1 = mysql_fetch_array( $add1 ))
echo "<tr><td>'.$list1['export_charges'].'&nbsp;$currency</td></tr>";
echo $currency; // This is working
}
```